# Why character / cuts the text in TextView if maxLines = 1?

Tags: android, view, textview, special-characters

**WHAT I HAVE**

I have a TextView who is showing a URL with "https://" prefix:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="test2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:id="@+id/txvNomEntornIversio" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="https://test2.sdasasdasdfasdfasdffasdfasdfasdf.sdffd"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:id="@+id/txvUrlEntorn"/>
        
    </LinearLayout>
```

**WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?**

The result in android studio preview and in device after execute the code was:

If execute previous code:
[image]

If I remove the "/" symbols:
[image]

If I move the symbol in other position:
[image]

**WHAT I NEED**

I need to show the prefix "https: //" with maximum letters to fit the available space.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried to [read documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) (setEllipsize block) and search in stackoverflow, searching for some reference with this symbol and nothing found.
I tried also to scape the symbols with no effect.

Anyone know why it occurs and can help me? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED LAYOUT**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/icon_unchecked"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/txvIconChecked"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="test2"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
            android:id="@+id/txvNomEntornIversio" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="https://mydomain.asdfasdasdfasdfasdffasdfasdfasdf.cat"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:id="@+id/txvUrlEntorn"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks to Teiky, we have found that this problem occurs only in versions lower than API 23. It may be a bug?

The option (deprecated) Android: SingleLine = "true" seems to work correctly in all versions! Instead, the new option android: MaxLines with android: ellipsize only works for 23 ...

At the moment, the most viable option seems to ignore deprecated SingleLine ...

**SOLUTION FOR ME**

Finally, as I said in the last update, my solution was to continue using android: SingleLine = true even if it is marked as deprecated.

Teikyo seconds, he tried a dipsositiu android 4.4.4 and worked well using MaxLines ellipsize ... and me, a device Lollipop I still cut the text to find the symbol / ...

Set in response Teikyo as good as it helped me to investigate the problem further. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: add an extra / into your line: e.g `https:///` The first / in the // is an escaping character

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I tried this: "https:///" with the same result... Also tried "https:\/\/" but no effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and the URL is fully display.
Maybe you should check these parameters, if you have enough width to display the complete URL:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

UPDATE by xikitidistant:

The solution isn't the weight and width="0dp". This was a code improve. The solution for me is updated in the question. Thanks for  your help.

Comment: Thanks Teiki. You are right, if I the url fits, this is showing correctly. But my win is show the maximum URL possible when the URL can't fit in aviable space, adding at the end the three points... I updated the code with the new view.

Comment: Wow, this is! I don't understand why this is not working for me.... Maybe becouse is an item in NavigationDrawer left menu with fixed 240dp width? Let me try compiling the last changes...

Comment: If you look at the previewer view of android studio also you see it correctly?

Comment: Wow! If you change the target to API 23 it works like your snap. Try to change it to lower than 23... it seems this was solved into new API 23

Comment: Yes you right. With API 22 the preview truncate the URL like you say. Have you try on emulator ? Maybe the problem just appear in the preview

Comment: Let me try and share the results. Now i can't do it.

Comment: I tried on a custom tablet 4.4.4 API 19. And it works fine.

Comment: I tried now in Lollipop device and this dosen't work without android:singleLine...

Answer (score 1):

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```